# MySQL INSERT INTO ... SELECT #1054 ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1054

Can anybody please help..

SELECT on its own works

INSERT on its own with VALUES works also.

note:

```
 products_similar has 2 columns VARCHARS
 get_cheaper() - stored routine returning VARCHAR
```

I never ever had problems with INSERT INTO ... SELECT.

But when I combine them I get error below:

SQL query: Documentation

```
INSERT INTO `products_similar` (
`product_sku` ,
`better_priced_sku`
)
SELECT p.product_sku sku, get_cheaper(
p.product_sku
)cheaper_sku
FROM jos_vm_product p;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'product_sku' in 'field list'

when I comment out get_cheaper(p.product_sku) cheaper_sku it works:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `products_similar` ;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
INSERT INTO `products_similar` (
`product_sku` ,
`better_priced_sku`
)
SELECT p.product_sku sku, p.product_sku sku# , get_cheaper(p.product_sku) cheaper_sku

FROM jos_vm_product p;# Affected rows: 43882
```

Comment: Just tried temporary table... but it gives me same error:

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table AS SELECT p.product_sku, get_cheaper(p.product_sku) better_priced_sku
FROM jos_vm_product p

Comment: I have one more clue, Problem is in stored procedure get_cheaper(). But it's mysql so finding this one is another topic.

Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this is due to the rename: `SELECT p.product_sku sku`. A column name of product_sku is expected.

Comment: That's definitely not it. I added aliases so to check if name makes any difference. And answer is NO.

Answer (score 0):

Does this part of your query work by it self?

```
SELECT p.product_sku sku, get_cheaper(p.product_sku)cheaper_sku
FROM jos_vm_product p;
```

Edit:

Since that works, try creating a view from it.

```
CREATE VIEW products_similar 
AS SELECT p.product_sku sku, get_cheaper(p.product_sku)cheaper_sku
FROM jos_vm_product p;
```

You will be able to query the view just like a normal table

Comment: Yes it does. Sorry for not making it more clear in post itself.
Insert alone, when i put values into it works as well. Just when I combine those two. I think it has to do with stored routine get_cheaper().... but have no idea why. Couldn't find any info in documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to this question from [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html):

The following column definitions demonstrate each possibility:

Auto-initialization and auto-update:
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Auto-initialization only:
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Auto-update only:
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Neither:
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0

You are interested in the last one - if you set the default value of the timestamp to 0 it will not be automaticly updated